# How do I retain the state of my ViewPager in my TabLayout when I'm replacing a Fragment on top of it?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, state, material-design

I have a single activity that uses a bunch of different Fragments. I have a TabContainer Fragment that holds a TabLayout which uses a ViewPager to handle tab navigation. Each Tab is its own Fragment.

In one of my tabs, I want to tap and place a fragment on top of my Tabbed fragment. This is meant to be a "details" sort of screen, so I don't want the tabs to be visible. I'm using this and it works as intended:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragmentToDisplay).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now, when I navigate back, the content in my tab is empty. The content in the tab directly next to that tab is also empty. When I navigate two tabs away, the content is recreated and the normal functionality returns. Why is content not being recreated on the tabs initially when I remove my "detail" fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was simply not passing the correct `FragmentManager` to the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

I needed to call `getChildFragmentManager()` on the Fragment, not `getSupportFragmentManager()` on the activity.

Thanks to these two posts for the answer:
[Fragment in ViewPager not restored after popBackStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600156/fragment-in-viewpager-not-restored-after-popbackstack)
and: [Replacing ViewPager with Fragment - Then Navigating Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490963/replacing-viewpager-with-fragment-then-navigating-back?rq=1)