# Nested fragments in viewpager with different menus

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Problem**

I want to create viewpager with 2 fragments in one Activity.
This fragments have different menu options, and one fragment is nested - by clicking listview item, opens same fragment with new data (`replace(), addToBackStack()`), but viewpager don't replacing correctly (when I do `transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, new TwoFragment())`.

I used this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020219/5576117, but I have different menu options, and menu options inflated from Fragment Container.

As a result if I create a new Fragment (as container) I just pass boolean extra `isContainer` to fragment and this works.
But now activity call wrong onOptionsItemSelected method (call from `fragment2`, when in viewpager selected `fragment1`).

**My code**

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
     ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
     viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
     setupViewPager(viewPager);

     TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
     viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
     mAdapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

     TwoFragment fragment = new TwoFragment();
     Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
     args.putBoolean(TwoFragment.ISCONTAINER_EXTRA, true);
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     mAdapter.addFragment(fragment, "TAB1");
     mAdapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "TAB2");
}
```

**OneFragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
     menu.clear();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // This method not called then this fragment selected in viewpager
     return true;
}
```

**TwoFragment:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Bundle extras = getArguments();
   if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(ISCONTAINER_EXTRA)) {
       isContainer = extras.getBoolean(ISCONTAINER_EXTRA);
   }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if (isContainer) {
       setHasOptionsMenu(false);
       FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.clRoot, new TwoFragment()).commit();
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Other actions
    return view;
    }

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_two, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // This method called then always
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.action_exit:
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Question**

How can I accomplish this without the use of third-party libraries?

*P.S: sorry for my bad english.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/ (In this case used viewpagerindicator library, but it can easily be replaced by tablayout).

Main idea: create root fragment, and in this fragment place your viewpager, tablayout and other fragments. All works fine.

Answer (score 1):

if i did understand you probably and your only issue is now that the option menu is not being displaying probably you could do this

```
 pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

this will `re-invalidate` the menu each time you select a page in the `fragment` and you can do the same every time you replace a `fragment` by  calling

```
((getActivity())AppCompatActivity).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

which will invalidate the menu on every replaced `fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried this, but also called wrong onOptionsItemSelected method.

Comment: can you please explain more by called wrong onOptionItemSelected? because if your menu is in the nestedFragment you'll have to implement onOptionsItemSelected within the nested fragment, not within the activity

Comment: Sorry for waiting, I meant what when in viewpager selected fragment2 called onOptionsItemSelected from fragment1.