# FragmentManager is already executing transactions when returning to view

Tags: xamarin.android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a view that has a tablayout that activates a viewpager, when viewing the page it works fine, but if I click on an item on that view and then go back to the past screen I get:

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

```cs
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    CurrentActivity = Activity;

    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_directory, null);

    _tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.directory_tabs);
    _viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.directory_pager);

    SetTabLayout();
    SetViewPager();

    return view;
}

private void SetTabLayout()
{
    var userTab = _tabLayout.NewTab();
    userTab.SetText("Users");

    var orgUnitsTab = _tabLayout.NewTab();
    orgUnitsTab.SetText("Organizations");

    _tabLayout.AddTab(userTab);
    _tabLayout.AddTab(orgUnitsTab);
    _tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
}

private void SetViewPager()
{
    var pagerAdapter = new DirectoryPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, _tabLayout.TabCount);

    _viewPager.Adapter = pagerAdapter;
    _viewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(_tabLayout));
}
```

not sure if it makes a difference but when I leave this view I go from a fragment to an activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you come across this question, I found a [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351068/778587) that answered it well.

the highlight, I should have used `ChildFragmentManager` instead of `FragmentManager`.